# Jenkins: how can I clean the workspace except the vagrant directory?

Tags: jenkins, vagrant

I have the following setup:

I use the [workspace cleanup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) in Jenkins to clean my workspace before each build. During my build-process I also trigger a `vagrant up` to setup a VM for phpunit tests:

```
$ vagrant up
$ ./runtest.sh
$ vagrant suspend
```

Now when I re-build the project, the VM gets build as a new one instead of just resuming the previous one. I guess this is because of the cleanup plugin removing the `.vagrant`-directory, therefore making Vagrant think it should build a new machine instead of just resuming the previous one.

Now I have configured the plugin to exclude the following patterns and I have the *'Apply pattern also on directories'*-checkbox also checked:

```
**/*.vagrant
.vagrant
.vagrant/
./.vagrant
./.vagrant/
```

But still the `.vagrant`-directory gets deleted from the workspace on each new build, spawning a brand new VM each time...

Does anyone know how I can exclude the `.vagrant`-directory from the workspace cleanup plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I was having a logical error. What I did as first task was checkout and hard-reset a specific branch to the master. So it was this step that actually deleted the `.vagrant`-directory after the cleanup-task did what it was expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin)**, it provides **include** and **exclude** patterns. You need to change the dropdown to **exclude** pattern (marked with arrow #2 in the diagram on plugin page), and type `.vagrant` in the pattern. Should probably also click "apply to directories"

Comment: I had this configured correctly, but it turned out I had a logical/thinking error. See my own answer